# Is it possible to merge these queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to merge these queries?

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE  users AS u, invites AS i 
              SET u.uinvite = u.uinvite - 1, u.ufriends = CONCAT(u.ufriends, ',$iid'), i.seen = 1
              WHERE u.uid = '$uid' AND i.invited_uid = '$uid' AND i.invitor_uid = '$iid'";
$sql2 = "UPDATE users
              SET ufriends = CONCAT(ufriends, ',$uid')
              WHERE uid = '$iid'";
```

Variable explanation:

```
$uid = the users ID            $iid = the friends ID
```

This was my attempt to merge:

```
$mergesql = "UPDATE invites AS i, users AS u 
                  SET
                      CASE
                      WHEN u.uid = '$uid' THEN u.uinvite=u.uinvite-1, u.ufriends = CONCAT(u.ufriends,',$iid')
                      ELSE u.ufriends = CONCAT(u.ufriends,',$uid')
                      END
                      , i.seen = '1'      
                  WHERE i.invited_uid = '$uid' AND i.invitor_uid = '$iid' 
                  AND (u.uid = '$uid' OR u.uid = '$iid')"
```

I find it hard to understand how mysql works when you have to do more complicated queries.
My English also lacks expertise, if you know a good tutorial, you can make me really happy with it! (not the one from the MySQL website, it's killing =S)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing MySQL, there is probably a way to do this in one query, but I don't think you would get any benefit at all because you are updating based on totally separate keys.  It might actually be dangerous to do this because the result would be unpredictable.  Doing it in two queries, it's easy to figure out what's going on.

If it's not too late, I would suggest that you remove the `friends` field in favor of a mapping table between users and friends.

Comment: How would you handle friends? (in php ;) ) I've got to check if someone is allowed to send another PMs. And I probably HAVE to use explode, don't I?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
$mergesql = "UPDATE
               users AS u,
               invites AS i,
               users AS uf
             SET
               u.uinvite = u.uinvite - 1, u.ufriends = CONCAT(u.ufriends, ',$iid'),
               i.seen = 1,
               uf.ufriends = CONCAT(uf.ufriends, ',$uid')
             WHERE u.uid = '$uid'
               AND i.invited_uid = '$uid' AND i.invitor_uid = '$iid'
               AND uid = '$iid'";
```

?